# Using on touch and on long click listener together for voice recording

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener

My scenario is like this.

Start the audio recording if user pressed the record button for more than 1 seconds otherwise consider it as a accidental touch and do not record.

We have tried a solution based on long click and touch listner and the code is below. But we cannot get the toast messages in proper order. the long click listener is invoked even if it is not long click.

```
imgViewMic.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     imgViewMic.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ACTION_DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ACTION_UP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
       return true;
       }
    });
 return true;
 }
});
```

Comment: using single listener instead of both .... i think long click is suitable for you situation.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

//Global varibles

```
    double startTime, deltaTime;
```

//Touch listener

```
    findViewById(R.id.mic).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                // Touch start time
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                // TouchEnd Time
                deltaTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

                // Difference > 1 Sec
                if (deltaTime > 1000) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record " + deltaTime / 1000 + " Sec", 300).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dont Record " + deltaTime / 1000 + " Sec", 300).show();
                }

                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. We have already tried this solution the problem with this approach is, we need to start the recording from the start itself right. In this approach it will start recording only after 1 second. If the user presses for more than 1 second it will not capture the recording on the first 1 second.